# how to play a video with cordova plugin vuforia

Tags: cordova, video, vuforia, alpha-transparency, chromakey

I have a mobile app made with cordova.

I want to add augmented reality and I installed the plugin vuforia.
I have configured my own image and it works me correctly, but I do not know how to launch a video. Also, I have a video with green background, channel alpha or chroma key...

Do you know any cordova plugin that launches the video when app recognize the image?

And with transparent background?

I do not care if the method is a plugin, html canvas code or javascript...
Thanks for your time.